# Postgres related process are running after stopping it

Tags: postgresql

Postgres related process are running after stopping it using the following stop command.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql stop
Stopping postgresql (via systemctl): postgresql.service
```

Postgres process

```
ps -ef | grep post
lxd         3433    3412  0 03:51 ?        00:00:00 postgres
lxd         3502    3433  0 03:51 ?        00:00:00 postgres: checkpointer 
lxd         3503    3433  0 03:51 ?        00:00:00 postgres: background writer 
lxd         3504    3433  0 03:51 ?        00:00:00 postgres: walwriter 
lxd         3505    3433  0 03:51 ?        00:00:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher 
lxd         3506    3433  0 03:51 ?        00:00:00 postgres: stats collector 
lxd         3507    3433  0 03:51 ?        00:00:00 postgres: logical replication launcher 
ubuntu      4180    2729  0 03:52 pts/0    00:00:00 grep post
```

Comment: Do you have a second postgres instance running inside an lxd container?

Comment: Not sure what is a lxd container

Comment: The timestamp, 03:51, was when Postgres started. A minute later, you ran the ps/grep command. I'd say that the init script is broken & is either crashing it causing a restart, or just restarting it. Regardless, why are you not stopping it via `systemctl`?